# Unable to inject a Managed Property with constructor

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to inject the @ManagedProperty(value = "#{ticketDataBean}"). I was able to do that but now I have declared a constructor in that since then its failing. Please guide.
 My code snippet

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{ticketDataBean}")
private TicketDataBean ticketDataBean; 


  public class TicketDataBean extends CreateTicketData implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String category;
private TicketingService service;
private static final transient Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TicketDataBean.class);

public TicketDataBean(final TicketingService service) {

    final net.atos.portlet.ticketing.model.UserInfo originalUser;
    this.service = service;
    originalUser = service.getDefaultReceiver();
    receiverId = originalUser != null ? originalUser.getId() : null;
    LOGGER.info("Reciever id in ticketdatabean---->" + receiverId);
}
```

Comment: what is the `TicketingService`? Is it an `EJB` or another `ManagedBean`?

Answer (score 0):

Managed beans are POJOs so they need to have non arguments constructor. If you want to initialize `service` you can do it in `@PostConstruct`. Better will be to create another `ManagedBean` for the `service` which you will be able to inject or you can create `@Singleton`.

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class TicketingService {
}
```

then you can inject it in this way (don't forget to add getter/setter tor it)

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{ticketingService}")
private TicketingService service;
```

You can read more about `ManagedBeans` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqm.html).